# Return application/json when an exception is thrown from spring boot example

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I've followed the tutorial [Accessing JPA Data with REST](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/) and when complete, I thought about adding validation using Hibernate Validator.

I annotated the entity's `firstName` and `lastName` properties with `@NotNull` and tried POSTing null values to the resource to see if those constraints would be honoured.

The server returned 406 due to a `ConstraintViolationImpl` exception as expected but the response entity was encoded as text/html, despite my having sent the header `Accept: application/json`.

What's the simplest way to modify the example to get the server to respond with application/json when an exception like this is thrown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to use Spring Boot Actuator (in 1.0) or use 1.1 (1.1.0.M2 just released). If you can't do that, you can add an `ErrorPage` for the 406 and/or a global `ErrorPage` and an MVC handler, mimicking the way the `ErrorController` works in Boot.